# How to print the results of a split in Java

Tags: java, split, println

How do I make this print the contents of b rather than its memory address?

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        String a = "A#b#C ";
        String[] b = a.split("#");
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) to print the String representation of your array: -

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b);
```

This will print your array like this: -

```
[A, b, C ]
```

---

Or, if you want to print each element separately without that `square brackets` at the ends, you can use `enhanced for-loop`: -

```
for(String val: b) {
    System.out.print(val + " ");
}
```

This will print your array like this: -

```
A b C
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want each element printed on a separate line, you can do this:

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        String a = "A#b#C ";
        String[] b = a.split("#");
        for (String s : b) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

For a result like `[A, b, C]`, use Rohit's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
String a = "A#b#C "; 
String[] b = a.split("#"); 

for( int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
System.out.println(b[i]);
}
```

Comment: That won't print the last element. You need `b.length` instead of `b.length - 1` (or else `<=` instead of `<`).